# Passing input to sed, and sed info to a string

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a list of files (~1000) and there is 1 file per line in my text file named: 'files.txt'

I have a macro that looks something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
b=$(sed '${1}q;d' files.txt)

cat > MyMacro_${1}.C << +EOF

myFile = new TFile("/MYPATHNAME/$b");

+EOF
```

and I use this input script by doing

```
./MakeMacro.sh 1
```

and later I want to do

```
./MakeMacro.sh 2
./MakeMacro.sh 3
```

...etc

So that it reads the n'th line of my files.txt and feeds that string to my created .C macro.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You need a `#include` in the generated code to define `TFile`, don't you?  And `myFile` too...and you run into problems if you link more than one of these thousand source files into a program...or there's some information missing.

Comment: Hi Jon. It turns out I do not actually. But that is a question better suited for a ROOT/c++ forum.  I simply wanna know how to pass the string into the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > So that it reads the n'th line of my files.txt and feeds that string to my created .C macro.

Given this statement and your tags, I'm going to answer using shell tools and not really address the issue of the .c macro.

The first line of your script contains a sed script.  There are numerous ways to get the *Nth* line from a text file.  The simplest might be to use `head` and `tail`.

```
$ head -n "${i}" files.txt | tail -n 1
```

This takes the first `$i` lines of `files.txt`, and shows you the last 1 lines of that set.

```
$ sed -ne "${i}p" files.txt
```

This use of sed uses `-n` to avoid printing by default, then prints the `$i`th line.  For better performance, try:

```
$ sed -ne "${i}{p;q;}" files.txt
```

This does the same, but quits after printing the line, so that `sed` doesn't bother traversing the rest of the file.

```
$ awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i' files.txt
```

This passes the shell variable `$i` into awk, then evaluates an expression that tests whether the number of records processed is the same as that variable.  If the expression evaluates true, awk prints the line.  For better performance, try:

```
$ awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print;exit}' files.txt
```

Like the second `sed` script above, this will quit after printing the line, so as to avoid traversing the rest of the file.

Plenty of ways you could do this by loading the file into an array as well, but those ways would take more memory and perform less well.  I'd use one-liners if you can.  :)

To take any of these one-liners and put it into your script, you already have the notation:

```
if expr "$i" : '[0-9][0-9]*$' >/dev/null; then
    b=$(sed -ne "${i}{p;q;}" files.txt)
else
    echo "ERROR: invalid line number" >&2; exit 1
fi
```

Comment: hi ghoti,

thanks for the reply I tried

    b=$(sed -ne "${1}{p;q;}" files.txt)

and it worked...thanks a bunch sir

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you can do a for loop in bash to call the script multiple times with different arguments.

```
for i in `seq 1 n`; do ./MakeMacro.sh $i; done
```

Based on the OP's comment, it seems that he wants to submit the generated files to Condor. You can modify the loop above to include the condor submission.

```
for i in `seq 1 n`; do ./MakeMacro.sh $i; condor_submit <OutputFile> ; done
```

Comment: well i will ultimately be submitting this to condor. So I am having condor use "MakeMacro.sh" mny times and submit them as individual jobs

Comment: @JaimeArturoGomez, What is your goal? To automate the submission of multiple jobs?

Comment: And each job takes the *output* of `MakeMacro.sh` or it **is** `MakeMacro.sh`?

Comment: hi merlin,sorry iwas out shopping. it takes the output of MakeMacro.sh and executes the new .C macro.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
while read file
do
    ((i++))
    cat > MyMacro_${i}.C <<-'EOF'

    myFile = new TFile("$file");

    EOF
done < files.txt
```

Beware: you need tab indents on the EOF line.

<s>I'm puzzled about why this is the way you want to do the job.  You could have your C++ code read `files.txt` at runtime and it would likely be more efficient in most ways.</s>

If you want to get the Nth line of `files.txt` into `MyMacro_N.C`, then:

```
{
echo
sed -n -e "${1}{s/.*/myFile = new TFILE(\"&\");/p;q;}" files.txt
echo
} > MyMacro_${1}.C
```

Comment: usually I would agree with you. However each file has about 50000 events to loop over, and each of those takes a while to process, so I want to use condor to submit one job on each file

Comment: I'm not familiar with 'condor' in this context -- is it [HTCondor](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/)?  Since you're generating source code, are you also compiling a separate program for each file?

Answer (score 0):

Good grief. The entire script should just be (untested):

```
awk -v nr="$1" 'NR==nr{printf "\nmyFile = new TFile(\"/MYPATHNAME/%s\");\n\n",$0 > ("MyMacro_"nr".C")}' files.txt
```

You can throw in a `;exit` before the `}` if performance is an issue but I doubt if it will be.